# Powershell query multidimensional hash

Tags: powershell, hashtable

I'm struggling creating and querying data of an object. (I think hash table)

- two environment (test and production)
- two servertypes per environment (webserver and appl servers)
- 1 or more servers of each type

I want to store the hostnames within the applicable section. I created the following hash:

```
$arr =@{}
    $arr.Environment = @{}
    $arr.Environment.Production = @{}
    $arr.Environment.Production.serverType = @{}
    $arr.Environment.Production.serverType.webServer = @{}
    $arr.Environment.Production.serverType.entServer = @{}

    $arr.Environment.Test = @{}
    $arr.Environment.Test.serverType = @{}
    $arr.Environment.Test.serverType.webServer = @{}
    $arr.Environment.Test.serverType.entServer = @{}
```

I found that I can access data like:

```
$serversArray.Environment.Test.serverType.webServer
```

I would like to know:

1. is this the right way of doing this? are there better / easier way to accomplish this?
2. how do I loop/filter this object, retrieving servernames that meet the specified criteria? Since I need to have 1. all test webservers then 2. all test appl servers etc

thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you're able to save all this in one go (using variables or hardcoded strings), you should be using the native format to store it - much more readable.

See

```
$Optiplex = @{
                'Brand' = 'Dell'
                'Model' = 'Optiplex'
                'Specs' = @{
                                'RAM' = '4 GB'
                                'CPU' = 'Intel i5'
                                'USB Ports' = '3'
                                'CD/DVD Drive' = 'No'
                                'HDD' = '320 GB - SSD'
                           } #Specs
             } #Optiplex
```

From [this walkthrough](https://fercorrales.com/having-fun-with-nested-hash-tables-building-a-hard-coded-db/)

You'll be able to access the variables for the hashtable in the same way, such as Optiplex.Specs.RAM to get the value for RAM.

Edit: To better answer question number 2, here's some idea on looping:

```
foreach ($serverTypeToKVs in $arr.Environment.Production.serverType.GetEnumerator()) {
    Write-Host "ServerType $(serverTypeToKVs.Name):"
    foreach ($keyVal in $serverTypeToKVs.Value.GetEnumerator()) {
      # Logic if serverTypeToKVs.Name == "webServer" 
      # Logic if keyVal == something
      # General work to be done
  }
}
```

Comment: This is indeed similar to what I currently have, but it does not answer my questions? (is this the appropriate way and how do I create loop or filter (based on variables)? to get only the server I need.

Comment: Ah yeah I didn't notice the loop question, but that depends what you need to compare, really. If you know the names of of all the structures that have nested objects inside of them, then the key/values inside IT are not nested, you can do something like

foreach ($serverTypeToKVs in $arr.Environment.Production.serverType.GetEnumerator()) {
Write-Host "ServerType $(serverTypeToKVs.Name):"
    foreach ($keyVal in $serverTypeToKVs.Value.GetEnumerator()) {
      # Logic if serverTypeToKVs.Name == "webServer" 
      # Logic if keyVal == something
      # General work to be done
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

I found following way to achieve this:

```
$order = @(("Test","Production"),("webServer", "entServer"))
        
foreach($env in $order[0]) {
    Write-Host "Environment: $env"
    foreach($svr in $order[1]) {
        Write-Host "ServerType: $svr"
        write-host "hostnames: "$serversArray.Environment.$($env).serverType.$($svr)
    }
}
```

This will loop the correct way/sequence and lists correct servers:

```
Environment: Test
ServerType: webServer
hostnames:  tweb1 tweb2
ServerType: appServer
hostnames:  tapp1
Environment: Production
ServerType: webServer
hostnames:  pweb1 pweb2 pweb3
ServerType: appServer
hostnames:  papp1 papp2 papp3 papp4
```